# How can I properly download a file from Google Cloud Storage to an Android app?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-storage

First of all, I can download from GCS using DownloadManager, the GCS java api, and the Android AsyncHttpClient. But the resulting file or file stream has headers in it, which prevents the file from being opened properly.

Example file saved by DownloadManager/GCS api/Android AsynHttpClient:

```
--5tc52jlLclf7f49cCw5hDvB1BwmZZB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="example.pdf"; filename="example.pdf"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

%PDF-1.4
%“Œ‹ž ReportLab Generated PDF document http://www.reportlab.com
% 'BasicFonts': class PDFDictionary
...
```

What libraries are available or how do I use any of the libraries I've tried to save the file properly so it does not have embedded header information? Preferably, I would like to use the header information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that got this working for me. I was able to use /r/n/r/n as a delimiter. Note, I modified [StorageFactory.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/json-api/src/main/java/StorageFactory.java) to use AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport() and to use a p12 keyfile. My version would be [here](https://github.com/hardyt/csci7799/blob/interface/GCPHealthcare/app/src/main/java/com/atrware/gcphealthcare/StorageFactory.java) if I could figure out why git is not adding my changes since last week.

```
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, GoogleCredential>() {
                @Override
                protected GoogleCredential doInBackground(Void... view) {
                    try {
                        Storage storage = StorageFactory.getService(credential);
                        Storage.Objects.Get getObject = storage.objects().get(BUCKET_NAME, fileName);
                        // Downloading data.
                        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(true);
                        getObject.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);

                        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream (
                                getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath()
                                        + "/" + fileName);


                        byte[] b = out.toByteArray();

                        final byte[] delimiter = BaseEncoding.base16().lowerCase().decode("0d0a0d0a".toLowerCase());
                        List<byte[]> byteArrays = new LinkedList<>();
                        int begin = 0;
                        outer:
                        for (int i = 0; i < b.length - delimiter.length + 1; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < delimiter.length; j++) {
                                if (b[i + j] != delimiter[j]) {
                                    continue outer;
                                }
                            }
                            byteArrays.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(b, begin, i));
                            begin = i + delimiter.length;
                            break;
                        }
                        byteArrays.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(b, begin, b.length));

                        outputStream.write(byteArrays.get(1));
                        outputStream.close();
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Created: " +
                                getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath()
                                + "/" + fileName);

                    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "GCS Api fail: " + e);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "GCS Api fail: " + e);
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "GCS Api fail: " + e);
                    }
                    return credential;
                }
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(final GoogleCredential credential) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "GCS completed.");
                    // Show file

                }
            }.execute();
```